# gomaasapi maintenance/support or is it a dead project?

Tags: maas

I'm curious about who the maintainer of the github.com/juju/gomaasapi repo is. It seems that nobody has been maintaining it for at least a year. I submitted a PR last night because my team is using the API for a project we're working on which implements MaaS instances via a Kubernetes controller in order to instantiate Kubernetes clusters in bare metal. Would someone please get back to me to answer the question of whether this API is still being officially supported?

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought that since it was in the juju repository, I sorta assumed that was an official repo. So, my apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a repo that is worked on by various Canonical teams, mostly the Juju and MAAS teams. You're right that it's not Ubuntu software in the Ubuntu archives, but pinging in IRC or discourse sites like discourse.maas.io or discourse.jujucharms.com is completely appropriate. Thanks for hacking on the code there. I'm sure we look forward to helping get your contribution into the codebase.